# Is user listing considered a vulnerability?

Tags: passwords, exploit, vulnerability, proxy, known-vulnerabilities

I couldn't find any other post on stack exchange talking about this.

I have found a way to get a website to list all users and their names. Is this considered a vulnerability? This website *does* have a bug bounty.

I think this might be a vulnerability, because an attacker could enumerate the user list and test the top 3 passwords or something, then switch to another proxy and try the next account. I don't know if this is worth reporting or not, however.

So here are my questions: Is this a vulnerability? What is its severity? Is it worth reporting? And if it is a vulnerability, what other ways could someone exploit this?

**Edit:** This question is talking about actually being able to list every single user and their names. *Not* just being able to check whether or not a user exists. I don't know how to "unmark" this as a duplicate.

Comment: this is definitely a vulnerability and worth reporting!

Comment: We have tons of questions about username enumeration. E.g. [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/158075/is-it-unsafe-to-show-message-that-username-account-does-not-exist-at-login), [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4729/should-usernames-be-kept-secret) and [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42872/user-name-enumeration).

Comment: @Arminius arent those questions all about if its secure to show that a user exists after the username has been entered? This questions seems to be about a issue where he can list all users.

Comment: @Dr.Fre In my opinion, the arguments in that case aren't fundamentally different. But if you think that's a separate issue that justifies an individual question, you might want to emphasize this aspect in the question and ask for a reopen.

Comment: It's not a wordpress site right ?

Comment: This is a request to reopen this question: I found a way to get the site to display a list of every single user's names (real name, but arbitrary, so it could also not be their real name) and usernames. I am not asking whether or not sites should hide the username on registration (or any of the other circumstances noted in the questions that @Arminus mentioned). I am asking if user listing is considered a vulnerability. The ability to not just check whether usernames exist or not, but to actually be able to get a list of every single user and their name.

Comment: @t.m.adam No, this is not a wordpress site. No CMS, in fact.

Comment: @Arminus I edited the question to emphasize the aspect of the question. Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just realized I was commenting from my second account. The @Arin user is me.

Comment: This question has been incorrectly marked as a duplicate. Please reopen it. Read the edit for an explanation of why I believe this is not a duplicate. Thank you.